# Generate a token for email verification in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, token

I'm building a login/reg system in CI3 and I have a doubt.
Instead of use:

```
$key=md5(uniqid());
```

for sending key for email activation...can I use another method? I don't know, using database (mysql)? hash with SHA1 maybe?
I don't want the most secure way, just a solution that is not fake as uniqid() is. 'Cause I know that id generated by uniqid() is not really random, so there is no reason to hash to md5 is simply...stupid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is that all methods that rely on randomness are subject to limitations of methods that your os/hardware can provide. That said, UUID should be enough in terms of uniqueness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually email verification/password generation should be

1. easy to understand
2. easy to get back

It means if you send **`md5`** what happen is user get an **word length of 32**. Its very bad sign.

**`MD5` example**

```
8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7
```

---

## what I Suggest you is

In codeigniter there is an helper call `String`. Use that.

There is 5 different choices to pick you

1. **alpha**
2. **alnum**
3. **basic**
4. **numeric**
5. **nozero**

---

## How to use this?

Load helper in controller

```
$this->load->helper('string');
```

Then just add this

```
random_string([$type [, $len]]) ;
```

**Example :**

```
random_string('alnum', 8);
```

---

## How these diff with each other ??

> Assume : length is 8 in these scenario.

***alpha***

This will just print **String with UPPER Case**
**Example** `AKTHDOGK`

***alnum***

This will print **String with UPPER and LOWER Case**
**Example** `JdKsPeeU`

***basic***

This will print **random number using `mt_rand()` in php**.
**Example** `12756079`

**numeric**

This will print **Numeric string**.
**Example** `01234567`  (Not used. So not sure)

***nozero***

This will print and  number. **But there is no zero**
**Example** `12345678`  (Not used. So not sure)

---

> **FYI:** I never used **numeric** and **nozero**. So i have no idea about the example. But all other function are i used.